# Meaning of 'in away' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the bold part (in away) mean in the following text?

> The total volume of water in the saturated sample must therefore be thought of as consisting of water that can, and water that cannot, **in away**.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either. Is it a saturated *solution*, ie water with the maximum possible solute dissolved in it, or is it a saturated with water, eg a cloth which is holding the maximum amount of water, or air at maximum humidity?

Comment: @Nima could you please provide a source for this quote or more of the surrounding text

Comment: Perhaps a space was lost,   "in a way".

Comment: @dubious It's from a TOEFL reading test. here is the whole paragraph: "Much of the water in a sample of water-saturated sediment or rock will drain from it if the sample is put in a suitable dry place. But some will remain, clinging to all solid surfaces. It is held there by the force of surface tension without which water would drain instantly from any wet surface, leaving it totally dry. The total volume of water in the saturated sample must therefore be thought of as consisting of water that can, and water that cannot, in away."

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah. maybe it's a typo. but I wasn't sure. that's why I asked here

Comment: It surely must be a typo for _drain away_.

Comment: [Drain away](http://toefl.weixue100.com/toefl/read/result?aeid=2677100) it is.  We did it, and Kate led the way. Away. In a way.

Comment: Thank you Yosef and Kate